# How to deconstruct a Python-like function call?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I had a function call as a string, like `"log(2, floor(9.4))"`. I want to deconstruct the call in a way that allows me to access the function name and arguments for the firstmost call and accurately deducts whether a function call as an argument is an argument or not.

For example, the arguments when deconstructing the string above would come to `[2, floor(9.4)]`

I've already tried to use some string parsing techniques (e.g. splitting on commas), but it doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `ast` module:

```py
import ast

data = "log(2, floor(9.4))"
parse_tree = ast.parse(data)

# ast.unparse() is for 3.9+ only.
# If using an earlier version, use the astunparse package instead.
result = [ast.unparse(node) for node in parse_tree.body[0].value.args]
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
['2', 'floor(9.4)']
```

I pulled the value to iterate over from manually inspecting the output of `ast.dump(parse_tree)`.

Note that I've written something a bit quick and dirty, since there's only one string to parse. If you're looking to parse a lot of these strings (or a larger program), you should create a subclass of [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor). If you want to also make modifications to the source code, you should create a subclass of [`ast.NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) instead.